# How to make child-element open a link when parent-element has attribute pointer-events: none?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help creating a card carousel that slides to the left or right when clicking the cards, and only opens a link when clicking on the card in the center. The first part (sliding the cards) is working. However, I'm having difficulties in figuring out how to make the centered card open a link after clicking it. I don't want the cards on the left and right to open the link, that's why all the cards have the `pointer-events:none` attribute.

I have tried to remove the `pointer-events:none` attribute for the center card (with `.center-card {pointer-events:auto;}`) but that didn't work. Also, removing the `pointer-events:none` from `.card` and adding it to the cards left and right, made the whole Javascript code useless.

I'm an absolute beginner in Javascript, so any help is greatly appreciated. Or, if a possible solution could be done with HTML/CSS only that would be terrific.

```js
const Cards = (() => {

  window.addEventListener(
    "DOMContentLoaded",
    () => {
      setTimeout(init, 1);
    },
    true
  );


  function init(e) {
    if (document.querySelector(".carousel")) {
      let cards = document.querySelector(".carousel");
      cards.addEventListener("click", clicked, false);
      document.querySelectorAll(".carousel .card")[1].click();
    }
  }


  function clicked(e) {
    let card = e.target;
    if (card.getAttribute("data-card")) {
      rearrange(card.getAttribute("data-card"));
    }
  }


  function rearrange(card) {
    let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel .card");
    for (let n = 0; n < cards.length; n++) {
      cards[n].classList.remove("card-left-left");
      cards[n].classList.remove("card-left");
      cards[n].classList.remove("card-center");
      cards[n].classList.remove("card-right");
      cards[n].classList.remove("card-right-right");
    }
    cards[card].classList.add("card-center");
    if (card == 0) {
      cards[3].classList.add("card-left-left");
      cards[4].classList.add("card-left");
      cards[1].classList.add("card-right");
      cards[2].classList.add("card-right-right");
    }
    if (card == 1) {
      cards[4].classList.add("card-left-left");
      cards[0].classList.add("card-left");
      cards[2].classList.add("card-right");
      cards[3].classList.add("card-right-right");
    }
    if (card == 2) {
      cards[0].classList.add("card-left-left");
      cards[1].classList.add("card-left");
      cards[3].classList.add("card-right");
      cards[4].classList.add("card-right-right");
    }
    if (card == 3) {
      cards[1].classList.add("card-left-left");
      cards[2].classList.add("card-left");
      cards[4].classList.add("card-right");
      cards[0].classList.add("card-right-right");
    }
    if (card == 4) {
      cards[2].classList.add("card-left-left");
      cards[3].classList.add("card-left");
      cards[0].classList.add("card-right");
      cards[1].classList.add("card-right-right");
    }
  }

  return {
    init
  };
})();
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Poppins, Roboto, Arial;
}

#container {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.carousel
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 75%;
  top: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card
{
  display: flex;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 20rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scale(1) translate(0px,0px) perspective(750px) rotateY(0deg);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}

.card *
{
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card-left-left {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(0.5) translate(-600px,0px) perspective(750px) rotateY(10deg);
  z-index: 0;
}

.card-left
{
  transform: scale(0.7) translate(-300px,0px) perspective( 750px ) rotateY(10deg);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  z-index: 1;
}

.card-center
{
  transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 0px) perspective( 750px ) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  z-index: 3;
}

.card-right
{
  transform: scale(0.7) translate(300px,0px) perspective( 750px ) rotateY(-10deg);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  z-index: 1;
}

.card-right-right {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(0.5) translate(600px,0px) perspective( 750px ) rotateY(-10deg);
  z-index: 0;
}

.card-image
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

.card-image img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.card-text
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 80%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-text p {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">       
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="card" data-card="0">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="https://www.arohatours.co.nz/media/1509/coromandel-hahai.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=600&height=450&rnd=131772666290000000&quality=80" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-text"><p>Tekst 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="1">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="https://www.arohatours.co.nz/media/1509/coromandel-hahai.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=600&height=450&rnd=131772666290000000&quality=80" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-text"><p>Tekst 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="2">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="https://www.arohatours.co.nz/media/1509/coromandel-hahai.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=600&height=450&rnd=131772666290000000&quality=80" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-text"><p>Tekst 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="3">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="https://www.arohatours.co.nz/media/1509/coromandel-hahai.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=600&height=450&rnd=131772666290000000&quality=80" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-text"><p>Tekst 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="4">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="https://www.arohatours.co.nz/media/1509/coromandel-hahai.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=600&height=450&rnd=131772666290000000&quality=80" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-text"><p>Tekst 5</p>
      </div>
    </div>   
  </div>
                                            
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any links in your HTML

Comment: keep `pointer-events:none` and add `pointer-events:auto` to child element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this. I felt like rewriting the rearrange function too, but this is minimum change needed

If you want to allow a click on the text too, you can add onclick
`location=hrefs[this.closest(".card").getAttribute("data-card")]`

```
const hrefs=["page1.html","page2.html","page3.html","page4.html","page5.html"]
function clicked(e) {
  let card = e.target;
  let index = card.getAttribute("data-card");
  if (card.getAttribute("data-card")) {
    if (card.classList.contains("card-center")) {
      location = hrefs[index]
    }
    else rearrange(index);
  }
}
```

```js
const Cards = (() => {

  window.addEventListener(
    "DOMContentLoaded",
    () => {
      setTimeout(init, 1);
    },
    true
  );


  function init(e) {
    if (document.querySelector(".carousel")) {
      let cards = document.querySelector(".carousel");
      cards.addEventListener("click", clicked, false);
      document.querySelectorAll(".carousel .card")[1].click();
    }
  }

  const hrefs = ["page1.html", "page2.html", "page3.html", "page4.html", "page5.hrml"]

  function clicked(e) {
    let card = e.target;
    let index = card.getAttribute("data-card");
    if (card.getAttribute("data-card")) {
      if (card.classList.contains("card-center")) {
        location = hrefs[index]
      } else rearrange(index);
    }
  }

  function arrayRotate(arr, count) {
    count -= arr.length * Math.floor(count / arr.length);
    arr.push.apply(arr, arr.splice(0, count));
    return arr;
  }
  let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  const cnt = {
    "-left-left": -2,
    "-left": -1,
    "-center": 0,
    "-right": 1,
    "-right-right": 2
  }
  const keys = Object.keys(cnt);

  function rearrange(card) {
    const cardDiv = document.querySelector('[data-card="' + card + '"]')
    const cardClass = cardDiv ? cardDiv.className.replace(/card|,-/g, "").trim() : "";
    const count = cnt[cardClass];
    if (count) {
      arrayRotate(arr, count)
    }
    arr.forEach((index, i) => {
      let thisCard = document.querySelector('[data-card="' + index + '"]')
      thisCard.className = "card card" + keys[i]
    })
    let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel .card");
  }

  return {
    init
  };
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Poppins, Roboto, Arial;
}

#container {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 75%;
  top: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 20rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 0px) perspective(750px) rotateY(0deg);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}

.card * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card-left-left {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(0.5) translate(-600px, 0px) perspective(750px) rotateY(10deg);
  z-index: 0;
}

.card-left {
  transform: scale(0.7) translate(-300px, 0px) perspective( 750px) rotateY(10deg);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 1;
}

.card-center {
  transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 0px) perspective( 750px) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 3;
}

.card-right {
  transform: scale(0.7) translate(300px, 0px) perspective( 750px) rotateY(-10deg);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: -1px 21px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 1;
}

.card-right-right {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(0.5) translate(600px, 0px) perspective( 750px) rotateY(-10deg);
  z-index: 0;
}

.card-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

.card-image img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.card-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 80%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-text p {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="card" data-card="0">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="https://www.arohatours.co.nz/media/1509/coromandel-hahai.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=600&height=450&rnd=131772666290000000&quality=80" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-text">
        <p>Tekst 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="1">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="https://www.arohatours.co.nz/media/1509/coromandel-hahai.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=600&height=450&rnd=131772666290000000&quality=80" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-text">
        <p>Tekst 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="2">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="https://www.arohatours.co.nz/media/1509/coromandel-hahai.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=600&height=450&rnd=131772666290000000&quality=80" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-text">
        <p>Tekst 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="3">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="https://www.arohatours.co.nz/media/1509/coromandel-hahai.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=600&height=450&rnd=131772666290000000&quality=80" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-text">
        <p>Tekst 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="4">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="https://www.arohatours.co.nz/media/1509/coromandel-hahai.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=600&height=450&rnd=131772666290000000&quality=80" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-text">
        <p>Tekst 5</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me. You got me curious with 'rewriting the rearrange function'. If you have time, could you please explain what could be done differently? If not, that's ok as well. Thanks again!

Comment: See updated script which I find more DRY than before